# Sonar C# Plugin S1172 false positive

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I've a class implementing `IEndpointBehavior` and don't implement all methods of the interface:

```
public class MyBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```

Documention of S1172 mentions:

> virtual, override methods and interface implementations are ignored.

Therefor I would expect to not have a S1172 thrown for `AddBindingParameters`, `ApplyDispatchBehavior` and `Validate` but Sonar throws an error on them.

Is this an issue in the documentation or a bug in the rule?